# Getting Invalid template file exception but everything seems to be fine?

Tags: magento2, admin, sales-order-view

#### app/code/Test/AreaCheckoutField/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Template" name="test_areacheckoutfield_order_area" template="Test_AreaCheckoutField::order/view/area.phtml" />
    </body>
</page>
```

#### app/code/Test/AreaCheckoutField/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/area.phtml

```
<h2>Reached</h2>
```

### Exception

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file: 'Test_AreaCheckoutField::order/view/area.phtml' in module: 'Test_AreaCheckoutField' block's name: 'test_areacheckoutfield_order_area'

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file: 'Test_AreaCheckoutField::order/view/area.phtml' in module: 'Test_AreaCheckoutField' block's name: 'test_areacheckoutfield_order_area'
#0 /var/www/html/insight3/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(300): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView(false)
#1 /var/www/html/insight3/vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Template.php(124): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#2 /var/www/html/insight3/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(667): Magento\Backend\Block\Template->_toHtml()
#3 /var/www/html/insight3/app/code/Test/AreaCheckoutField/Plugin/Block/Adminhtml/SalesOrderViewInfo.php(28): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#4 /var/www/html/insight3/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Test\AreaCheckoutField\Plugin\Block\Adminhtml\SalesOrderViewInfo->afterToHtml(Object(Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Info\Interceptor), '\n<section class...')
#5 /var/www/html/insight3/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Info\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#6 /var/www/html/insight3/generated/code/Magento/Sales/Block/Adminhtml/Order/View/Info/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Info\Interceptor->___callPlugins('toHtml', Array, Array)
#7 /var/www/html/insight3/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(558): Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Info\Interceptor->toHtml()
#8 /var/www/html/insight3/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(534): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('order_info')
#9 /var/www/html/insight3/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('order_info')
#10 /var/www/html/insight3/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(507): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('order_info', true)
#11 /var/www/html/insight3/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/tab/info.phtml(17): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->getChildHtml('order_info')
#12 /var/www/html/insight3/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/var/www/html/i...')
#13 /var/www/html/insight3/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(270): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Info), '/var/www/html/i...', Array)
#14 /var/www/html/insight3/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(300): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/var/www/html/i...')
#15 /var/www/html/insight3/vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Template.php(124): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#16 /var/www/html/insight3/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(667): Magento\Backend\Block\Template->_toHtml()
#17 /var/www/html/insight3/vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Widget/Tabs.php(390): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#18 /var/www/html/insight3/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/widget/tabs.phtml(57): Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tabs->getTabContent(Object(Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Info))
#19 /var/www/html/insight3/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/var/www/html/i...')
#20 /var/www/html/insight3/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(270): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tabs), '/var/www/html/i...', Array)
#21 /var/www/html/insight3/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(300): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/var/www/html/i...')
#22 /var/www/html/insight3/vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Template.php(124): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#23 /var/www/html/insight3/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(667): Magento\Backend\Block\Template->_toHtml()
#24 /var/www/html/insight3/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(558): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#25 /var/www/html/insight3/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(534): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('sales_order_tab...')
#26 /var/www/html/insight3/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('sales_order_tab...')
#27 /var/www/html/insight3/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(586): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('sales_order_tab...', false)
#28 /var/www/html/insight3/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('left', false)
#29 /var/www/html/insight3/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('left')
#30 /var/www/html/insight3/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(586): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('left', false)
#31 /var/www/html/insight3/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('side.col', false)
#32 /var/www/html/insight3/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('side.col')
#33 /var/www/html/insight3/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(586): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('side.col', false)
#34 /var/www/html/insight3/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.main.conta...', false)
#35 /var/www/html/insight3/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.main.conta...')
#36 /var/www/html/insight3/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(586): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.main.conta...', false)
#37 /var/www/html/insight3/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.content', false)
#38 /var/www/html/insight3/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.content')
#39 /var/www/html/insight3/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(586): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.content', false)
#40 /var/www/html/insight3/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.wrapper', false)
#41 /var/www/html/insight3/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#42 /var/www/html/insight3/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(586): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.wrapper', false)
#43 /var/www/html/insight3/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('backend.page', false)
#44 /var/www/html/insight3/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('backend.page')
#45 /var/www/html/insight3/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(586): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('backend.page', false)
#46 /var/www/html/insight3/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('root', false)
#47 /var/www/html/insight3/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#48 /var/www/html/insight3/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(955): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('root')
#49 /var/www/html/insight3/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(50): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput()
#50 /var/www/html/insight3/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(257): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput()
#51 /var/www/html/insight3/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php(170): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#52 /var/www/html/insight3/generated/code/Magento/Backend/Model/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#53 /var/www/html/insight3/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(139): Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#54 /var/www/html/insight3/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#55 /var/www/html/insight3/pub/index.php(37): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#56 {main}
```

Comment: where you want to call this block?

Comment: admin order view, in the info tab... I am using a plugin to call this block.. As we can see that the calling the block part is doing it's work nicely... But I don't know why the block is throwing this exception.. Tried to create a custom block in my module and call the template from there using `protected $_template` field.. But the result was the same exception...